# Firebird excessive logging

Tags: hibernate, jdbc, firebird, jaybird

I'm using WildFly 10 with Hibernate and some JDBC.
I have no logs at all If I declare my data source like this:

```
<datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:jboss/Firebird" pool-name="FirebirdPool" enabled="true" spy="true" use-ccm="true" statistics-enabled="false">
<connection-url>jdbc:firebirdsql:localhost/3050:C:\banco\COMPLEXO140116.FDB</connection-url>
```

But if I declare passing:

```
?defaultResultSetHoldable=True&amp;encoding=WIN1252
```

it logs

> 09:54:00,384 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper (default task-3) SQL Warning Code: 0, SQLState: 01000
>
> 09:54:00,384 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default
> task-3) null

at every query

Comment: These log messages are generated by Hibernate, do you have more info like a stacktrace or error message? Have you tried which of the two properties cause this (my guess would be `defaultResultSetHoldable=true`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logging is done by Hibernate, not by Firebird or Jaybird. The reason this happens is because you have specified `defaultResultSetHoldable=True`. This setting will make all statements have holdability `HOLD_CURSORS_OVER_COMMIT`. In Jaybird `HOLD_CURSORS_OVER_COMMIT` is implemented by using `TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE`, but the default is `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY`, so Jaybird upgrades the result set type, and in compliance with the JDBC specification (section 15.1.1 of JDBC 4.2), this registers a warning which is then logged by Hibernate.

> If the driver does not support the type supplied to the methods `createStatement`, `prepareStatement`, or `prepareCall`, it generates an `SQLWarning` on the Connection object that is creating the statement.

Unfortunately, a bug in the `SQLWarning` subclass used by Jaybird causes the message to be `null` instead of the actual message (*"Holdable result set must be scrollable."*).

Your options are either not specifying `defaultResultSetHoldable=True` or configuring Hibernate to not log warnings using configuration property `hibernate.jdbc.log.warnings=false`.

Out of curiosity: why are you specifying `defaultResultSetHoldable=True`? It is an option that can be bad for performance as it caches the entire result set in the driver, and it is primarily intended as a workaround for applications that try to access the result set after (auto) commit.

Comment: I have a JSF application that uses JasperReport, when it calls the generation of PDF if the option `defaultResultSetHoldable=True` is not set, then I have an error. This is a known issue: [link](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=jasper+reports+"defaultResultSetHoldable%3DTrue")

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at jasper reports, because it sounds like it is trying to use the result set after it has been closed.  In auto commit, executing another statement on the same connection closes the result set of earlier executed statements as required by the JDBC specification.

Comment: So, in this case, should I have a connection with this parameter only for Jasper and another connection to the rest of application?

Comment: @erickdeoliveiraleal That would be advisable yes.

Comment: We are using defaultResultSetHoldable=True since we are batch processing large volumes of data using hibernate. We have millions of datasets and a commit size of about 1000. Another way to get rid of the warnings is to overwrite  isJdbcLogWarningsEnabledByDefault in your own Firebird Dialect class.

Comment: @B_St If you are processing large volumes of data, it might be advisable not to use defaultResultSetHoldable=true as it will result in more memory consumption as the whole result set is loaded into memory first.

Comment: But if we use defaultResultSetHoldable=false the cursor will break as soon as we commit. How can we solve this problem?

Comment: @B_St Consider not committing, and use a read-only (read committed) transaction if you are concerned about the effects of long living transaction.